# Java Type Inference in Static Methods

Tags: java, static-methods, type-inference

Scenario: I need to handle a request and response scenario where the inner objects of request/response depends on the request code.
so I did a method like below.

```
public static <T, U> Response getResponse(String requestCode, Request req) {
        Response response = new Response();

        T requestObject = (T) req.getInnerObject();

        RequestHandler<T, U> requestHandler = new RequestHandler<T, U>(
                requestCode, requestObject);

        U responseObject = requestHandler.getResponse();

        response.setInnerObject(responseObject);

        return response;
}
```

The question is, How do I specify the `T` and U when calling this method? 
I'm surprised that I can do

```
Response response = getResponse(requestCode, req);
```

Where have I got it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `Response response = getResponse(requestCode, req);` is valid. If you want to force generics parameters, you can do `YourClass.<MyTClass, MyUClass>getResponse(requestCode, req)`.

Comment: As long as your `Response` class is not Generic there is no point in specifying any `T` and `U`. Your type cast `(T)` inside the method is *unsafe* and the actual type for `U` does not matter as `setInnerObject` seems to accept arbitrary `Object`s. You *can* specify types for `T` and `U` and you can specify *anything* for them, it simply has not the slightest effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specifiy T and U, you can call your method like this :

```
YourClass.<MyTClass, MyUClass>getResponse(requestCode, req);
```

Calling `Response response = getResponse(requestCode, req);` is as valid as calling `new ArrayList()` instead of `new ArrayList<String>()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `generic method`. Generic methods are methods that introduce their own type parameters. This is similar to declaring a generic type, but the type parameter's scope is limited to the method where it is declared. Static and non-static generic methods are allowed, as well as generic class constructors.

To reference the generic method within your code, you must perform a generic type invocation, which replaces T and U with some concrete value, such as Integer:

```
SomeClass.<Integer, String>getResponse(requestCode, req);
```

Sometimes, the explicitly provided types can be left out and the compiler will infer the type that is needed. This feature, known as type inference, allows you to invoke a generic method as an ordinary method, without specifying a type between angle brackets. Read about [type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) to know more about this.